# How to make line end in the middle of line by "..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**[i want to know how to make line end in the middle of line as in the image attached in **objective c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78s0c.png)****

Comment: Are you want dotted line at the end ?

Comment: yes doted line at the middle with no any text after that

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged `UILabel`. UILabels can truncate at head, middle and tail. Select the label in Interface Builder in Xcode and choose your preferred option in the **Line Break** pop-up button.

Comment: i dont mean that
i have attached an image within it.
i just wanted to display a long sentences to be seen in one and a half line with "..." at last